# "Such-and-such (a)" + singular noun

Tags: adjectives, indefinite-articles, determiners

I've found both versions, [*She lives in such-and-such **a** street*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles-espanol/such-and-such) AND [*She lives in such-and-such street*](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=such%20and%20such)

Are both uses of the [determiner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/such_and_such)? Which is the right one?

[OED entry for *such*](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00241458)

Comment: The full OED's most recent citation for this usage is 1899: *It became the custom to ask what coffee~house such-and-such a man frequented*, which ***does*** have an article, because it could reasonably be replaced by just the single word ***such***. But they also cite Thackeray *Newcomes* (1855) with *Lord and Lady Blank, of Suchandsuch Castle.* Which ***doesn't*** have an article (because you can't really reduce that one to ***such*** - it's more like the adjectival qualifier ***of unspecified name***, placed before rather than after the noun it modifies).

Comment: **Hamlet** - *I saw him yesterday, or th'other day, Or then, or then, with such and such.* Where today we'd more likely say ***with so-and-so*** to reference "'person of unspecified name". But in principle we *could* include an article/determiner with the modernised version of The Bard's context - ***with some so-and-so***, for example, would definitely *amplify* the dismissive implications there (even if I know the relevant name, it's so unimportant I won't bother saying it), imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers https://www.oed.com/oed2/00241458. Also relevant, (Adj) [before a noun] being the person or thing or the persons or _things indicated: _If any member be late, **such** member shall be suspended https://www.wordreference.com/definition/such

Comment: Note that whatever works for _such-and-such_ must be qualified by whatever works with _so-and-so_, since _such_ and _so_ are effectively the same morpheme. _Such_ is used before nouns, with an article if necessary, while _so_ is used before adjectives. The reduplicated conjoined forms can often be used interchangeably, showing that they're newly derived.

Comment: @JohnLawler OED **so**, adv. and conj. https://oed.com/oed2/00229614

Comment: why is the indefinite article used in [_at such and such **a** place_](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/such%20and%20such)  but not in [_such and such kind of people_](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/such%20and%20such)?

Comment: _in **such** manner as to follow or result from_ https://www.wordreference.com/definition/so

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting, and there does seem to be divided usage. [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such+and+such+a+street%2Csuch+and+such+street&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuch%20and%20such%20a%20street%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuch%20and%20such%20street%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csuch%20and%20such%20a%20street%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuch%20and%20such%20street%3B%2Cc0) for *such and such a street* and *such and such street* (and a check on references given at the link) show that both are used (with various choices of hyphenation), the one containing the article 'a' being five times as common a choice.

This is probably because there is an attempt to conform to standard grammar, though logically 'such and such a' is no better than 'such and such' as a placeholder some would portray as _____ or XXXX.

[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/such-and-such#:%7E:text=You%20use%20such%20and%20such,%5Bspoken%2C%20vagueness%5D) does not analyse **such and such** more than to call the whole a phrase; when used before a noun, the near-equivalence of 'some' might make some argue for determiner classification. And Collins does not even comment on the fact that *a* is typically included before a noun. As seen below, the distribution of 'such and such [a]' is fairly wide, not merely prenominal:

**such and such** [phrase]:

> You use *such and such* to refer to a thing or person when you do not
> want to be exact or precise. [spoken, vagueness]
>
> - *I said, 'Well what time'll I get to Leeds?' and he said such and such a time but I missed my connection*.
> - *He'd like to give a course of lectures on such and such a topic.*
> - *we went to such and such a place* [from Webster's]
> - *Or that the friend you trusted was going to betray you in some way on such and such a date?* [Anthony Masters: *Cascades - The Day of the
>   Dead*]
> - *And so we produce masses of documented research to define a target audience in such and such a demographic.* [Stuart Harrison: *Better
>   than This*]

The last example is more unusual, as 'such and such [a]' is, as
Collins adds, usually used in informal contexts.

[re-ordered]

Collins includes examples where 'such and such' is not used before a noun, and the 'a' is inappropriate:

> - *What if such and such had happened instead?* [used ostensibly as a noun phrase]
> - *Father, forgive me for I have sinned, she said, my last confession was such and such ago.* [Louise Erdrich: The Last Report on ...] [used
>   ostensibly as a measure phrase]

Comment: Relevant info: https://www.wordreference.com/definition/such

Comment: (Adj) [before a noun] being the person or thing or the persons or things indicated:
_If any member be late, **such** member shall be suspended_

Comment: The full OED lists this usage under Section III, definition 16b *Used to indicate or suggest a name, designation, number, or quantity, where the speaker or writer prefers or is obliged to substitute a general phrase for **the specific term** that would be required in a particular instance.* Within which they list examples with and without the article.  But for my money, *He lives on such-and-such **a** street* is "weird", cos I can't directly replace "such-and-such" by "[name unspecified]" the way I could with "Madonna lived in such-and-such castle". Where *syntactically* it's a "proper noun".

Comment: (In most contexts, ***the specific term*** being "a proper noun", imho.)

Comment: OED https://www.oed.com/oed2/00241458

Comment: why is the indefinite article used in [_at such and such **a** place_](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/such%20and%20such)  but not in [_such and such kind of people_](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/such%20and%20such)?